# More information on output array with equation and indicies

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have a math function whose output is defined by two variables, `x` and `y`.

The function is `e^(x^3 + y^2)`.

I want to calculate every possible integer combination between 1 and some defined integer for `x` and `y`, and place them in an array so that each output is aligned with the cooresponding `x` value and `y` value index. So something like:

given:

```
x = 3
y = 5
```

output would be an array like this:

```
f(1,1) f(1,2) f(1,3)
f(2,1) f(2,2) f(2,3)
f(3,1) f(3,2) f(3,3)
f(4,1) f(4,2) f(4,3)
f(5,1) f(5,2) f(5,3)
```

I feel like this is an easy problem to tackle but I have limited knowledge. The code that follows is the best description.

```
import math 
import numpy as np

equation = math.exp(x**3 + y**2)

#start at 1, not zero
i = 1
j = 1

#i want an array output
output = []

#function
def shape_f (i,j):
    shape = []
    output.append(shape)
    while i < x + 1:
        while j < y +1: 
            return math.exp(i**3 + j**2)

#increase counter
i = i +1
j = j +1
print output
```

I've gotten a blank array recently but I have also gotten one value (int instead of an array)

Comment: You need to read more about basic iterations in python.  `while` loops don't auto increment.

Comment: There's a couple of really obvious problems you should probably look into before posting here. You import `numpy` as `np`, but don't actually use it anywhere, which is a red flag. But more importantly, you're trying to loop (`while`) over something, but increment the loop control variable outside the loop - that'll never work.

Comment: If you used `np.exp` you could pass whole arrays to your func, instead of iterating one scalar pair at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you have an indentation error, but it looks like you never do anything with the output of the function `shape_f`.  You should define your equation as a function, rather than expression assignment.   Then you can make a function that populates a list of lists as you describes.

```
import math

def equation(x, y):
    return math.exp(x**3 + y**2)

def make_matrix(x_max, y_max, x_min=1, y_min=1):
    out = []
    for i in range(x_min, x_max+1):
        row = []
        for j in range(y_min, y_max+1):
            row.append(equation(i, j))
        out.append(row)
    return out

matrix = make_matrix(3, 3)
matrix
# returns:
[[7.38905609893065, 148.4131591025766, 22026.465794806718],
 [8103.083927575384, 162754.79141900392, 24154952.7535753],
 [1446257064291.475, 29048849665247.426, 4311231547115195.0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do this very simply with `numpy`.

First, we use `np.arange` to generate a range of values from 0 (to simplify indexing) to a maximum value for both `x` and `y`. We can perform exponentiation, in a vectorised manner, to get the values of `x^3` and `y^2`.

Next, we can apply `np.add` on the outer product of `x^3` and `y^3` to get every possible combination thereof. The final step is taking the natural exponential of the result:

```
x_max = 3
y_max = 5

x = np.arange(x_max + 1) ** 3
y = np.arange(y_max + 1) ** 2

result = np.e ** np.add.outer(x, y)

print(result[2, 3]) # e^(2 ** 3 + 3 ** 2)
```

Output:

```
24154952.753575277
```

Comment: the +1 should be outside the arange (see my answer). `np.e ** ...` is probably better expressed as ` np.exp(...)`, but I like your use of outer in place of broadcasting.

Comment: The reason the `+1` is inside is that it allows `result[x, y]` to map naturally to `f(x, y)`.

Comment: OP is looking to start the indexing at 1, but that's a valid approach nevertheless since it yields a superset of the answer

Answer (score 0):

A trivial solution would be to use the [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) feature of numpy with the [`exp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.exp.html) function:

```
x = 3
y = 5

i = np.arange(y).reshape(-1, 1) + 1
j = np.arange(x).reshape(1, -1) + 1

result = np.exp(j**3 + y**2)
```

The [`reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) operations make `i` into a column with `y` elements and `j` into a row with `x` elements. Exponentiation does not change those shapes. Broadcasting happens when you add the two arrays together. The unit dimensions in one array get expanded to the corresponding dimension in the other. The result is a `y`-by-`x` matrix.